# What is the probability that a leap year selected at random will contain 53 tuesdays?

Tags: probability

A leap year consists of 366 days.

A leap year consists of 52 weeks(i.e. 364 days) and 2 days.

Comment: A very good explanation can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779660/probability-that-a-leap-year-has-52-sundays

Answer (score 6):

There are 53 Tuesdays in a leap year if it starts on a Monday or Tuesday.

This **can't** happen in 2/7 of all leap years, because the distribution of leap years **and** first-days-of-the year repeats every 400 years. There are 97 leap years in each such period, which is not a multiple of 7.

More precisely, in every 400-year period,

- 13 leap years start on a Monday
- 14 leap years start on a Tuesday
- 14 leap years start on a Wednesday
- 13 leap years start on a Thursday
- 15 leap years start on a Friday
- 13 leap years start on a Saturday
- 15 leap years start on a Sunday

So the probablility that a leap year chosen uniformly among the leap years in a cycle starts on a Monday or Tuesday (and so contains 53 Tuesdays) is
$$ \frac{13+14}{97} = \frac{27}{97} \qquad (= \tfrac27-\tfrac{5}{679}) $$

Comment: Yeah, this is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

The Gregorian calendar repeats every 400 years (because there are 97 leap years every 400 years, and $400(365)+97$ is a multiple of $7$), so it suffices to count the number of leap years in the period from $1601$ to $2000$ that contain 53 Tuesdays.

In the first 84 years of each century, there will be 21 leap years (xx04, xx08, ..., xx84). Because these leap years occur at regular intervals, 3 of them will start on each day of the week. So 6 will start on a Monday or a Tuesday each century; this gives $24$ leap years that start on a Monday or a Tuesday in the first $84$ years of each century in the overall time frame.

It remains to count how many leap years in the last $16$ years of each century start on a Monday or a Tuesday. Note that if year $x$ is a leap year, year $x+4$ will always start on the weekday two days earlier than year $x$, because $4(365)+1 \equiv -2 \pmod{7}$. Also, if year $x$ is not in the final century of a Gregorian cycle, year $x+100$ will *also* always start on the weekday two days earlier than year $x$, because $100(365) + 24 \equiv -2 \pmod{7}$. Finally, it can be seen that $1688$ [starts on a Thursday](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1688&country=22) in the Gregorian calendar. So:

- **$1692$ starts on a Tuesday** and $1696$ starts on a Sunday (adding $1$ to the count).
- **$1788$ starts on a Tuesday**, $1792$ starts on a Sunday, and $1796$ starts on a Friday (adding $1$ to the count).
- $1888$ starts on a Sunday, $1892$ starts on a Friday, and $1896$ starts on a Wednesday (adding $0$ to the count).
- $1988$ starts on a Friday, $1992$ starts on a Wednesday, **$1996$ starts on a Monday**, and $2000$ starts on a Saturday (adding 1 to the count).

Adding these to the $24$ from before gives a total of $27$ leap years that start on a Monday or Tuesday in a single calendar period. As there are $97$ leap years total in that period, the probability that a given one starts on a Monday or a Tuesday is $\dfrac{27}{97}$.

Comment: You can simplify that calculation a bit by instead considering the period 1700 to 2199. Then the 49 regularly-spaced leap years from 1904 to 2196 split evenly between the weekdays, and then the only "sporadic" years you need to consider are three from the 1700s and three of the 1800s. -- Say, 1788, 1792, 1796, 1804, 1808, 1812.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thanks, good point! I'll have to remember that the next time this comes up...

Comment: (and of course I meant 2099 and 2096 where I wrote 2199 and 2196).

Answer (score 1):

It's 2/7. These are the cases: 1. The 2 extra days are monday and tuesday 2. The 2 extra days are tuesday and wednesday, until the 7th case wherein the 2 extra days are sunday and monday out of the 7 cases, only 2 contain tuesday. Thus 2/7

Comment: You're assuming that the year is equally likely to start on each of the seven days of the week, which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it obvious that its gonna be 1/7? Any day of the week can be one of those two days and therefore how the chance of appearing 53 times. This makes the chances even for all of the days.

Comment: You're answering the wrong question.  We've picked the day of the week we want to match.  The fact that we'd get the same answer if we chose Thursday or Saturday doesn't come into play.

Comment: @John, thanks for the comment but I don't understand what you mean by "we already picked the day of the week we want to match?". So then what is the probability space that I am missing?

Comment: Forgetting for a second that the distribution isn't uniform (see the upvoted answers), the probability of getting 53 Whateverdays in that year is $2/7$.  All of the probabilities are equal, but there is overlap with one of the other cases.  I can have 53 Mondays and 53 Tuesdays in one year.  I can also have 53 Tuesdays and 53 Wednesdays in one year.  Both of these cases imply 53 Tuesdays.  But the odds of having 53 Tuesdays is 2/7.  I picked which day I want to test.

Answer (score 0):

There will be 366 days in a leap year. 366/7 = 52 weeks + 2 additional days. These days can be :

Sun, Mon

Mon, Tue

Tue, Wed

Wed, Thu

Thu, Fri

Fri, Sat

Sat, Sun

Total no. of elementary outcomes : 7

Total no. of possible outcomes of getting a tuesday : 2

probability of the event = 2/7

Answer (score 0):

There are total $366$ days in a leap year. So $\frac{366}{7}=52$ weeks + $2$(additional days). Total number of outcomes is $7$ and possible outcomes is $2$. Therefore, $p(E)$ of the event is $\frac27$.

Answer (score 0):

In a leap year days are arranged as:
                          52×7+2
(+2)can be any day.so probability of getting a Sunday in leap year is 2/7