# Probability that a leap year has 52 Sundays

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

For the Question "Find the probability that a leap year has ***53*** Sundays".

The Solution goes :

For 53 Sundays, we proceed as: $\frac{366}{7} = 52.28$; So we can be sure that there are 52 Sundays, now the only question is of the 1 Sunday. So $7\cdot 52 = 364$. Therefore the remaining 2 days (366-364) decide the probability of being a Sunday. So we consider pairings of 2 consecutive days -

1. Sunday-Monday
2. Monday-Tuesday
3. Tuesday-Wednesday
4. Wednesday-Thursday
5. Thursday-Friday
6. Friday-Saturday
7. Saturday-Sunday

So out of the 7 pairs, we have 2 pairs that include a Sunday. Therefore the probability of having 53 Sundays in a Leap Year is $\frac{2}{7}$.

Then I was wondering, what if we ask "Probability that a leap year has ***52*** Sundays", Considering the above solution for ***53*** Sundays, the answer to the ***52*** Sundays problem should be 1. (Since $\frac{366}{7} = 52.28$) So we have complete 52 weeks and hence always 52 Sundays, therefore 1.

I found some online forums, where the answer to $52$ Sundays Problem is not 1. Hence my confusion. Please help.

Comment: Does "has 52 Sundays" mean "has at least 52 Sundays" or "has exactly 52 Sundays"?

Comment: Has exactly 52 Sundays.

Comment: Is the logic to find P(53 Sundays) that I have mentioned correct?

Answer (score 7):

By the way, the exact probability that a leap year has 53 Sundays is a bit higher than 2/7: The distribution of days of the week repeats exactly every 400 years: January 1st, 2000, was a Saturday, as will be January 1st, 2400. Within these 400 years, there are 97 leap years, 28 of which start on a Saturday or Sunday; so the probability is $28/97\approx 0.28866$ rather than $2/7\approx 0.28571$.

Answer (score 1):

Probability that leap year has 52 Sundays is 5/7

Answer (score 0):

if it asked:"What is the Probability that a leap year has **exactly** 52 Sundays ?", than you can work with the converse probability.

greeting,

calculus

Comment: So would that be 1 - P(atleast 52 Sundays)? In that case how do I calcualte P(atleast 52 Sundays)?

Comment: No it is $P(X=52)=1-P(X=53)$ -- A year has 52 or 53 sundays. So the probability for at least 52 sundays is one.

Answer (score 0):

A leap year has  52 weeks + 2 extra days;
There are 52 Sundays in 52 weeks;
If either of the 2 extra days is Sunday then there will be 53 Sundays in a week;
Probability of any one of that extra days is Sunday = Probabilty of 53 Sundays in a week  =2/7;
Probability That any day of the 2 extra days is not sunday = Probability of only 52 Sundays in a week = 1 - 2/7 
                     = 5/7

Comment: Use Mathjax please.